# Check if a URL takes you to an available destination - iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection

In my iPad app, I am creating an NSURLConnection, and when a valid URL is provided, then I can read the returned data from the host.  However, when I put in an invalid URL, the app crashes when I try to make the request.

What is the easiest way to determine if a URL is pointing to a host that can be accessed?

I saw that Apple has a reachability tutorial, but that does not allow you to check if a specific host can be reached.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection delegate methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: If you're using an http connection then it's also worth catching connection:didReceiveResponse: and checking the response code (you'll get an NSHTTPURLResponse rather than a plain NSURLResponse). Otherwise you may get, say, a 500 response code (internal server error) but an otherwise valid connection that returns data (usually a web page telling you there's been a 500 error), and hence not otherwise spot the problem and react incorrectly.